# Run a function if a variable (from an other class) get changed (C#)

Tags: c#, events

I have a C# WPF program which downloads a file. The code for downloading the file is Written into a class called "Download". In this class i have public static double called "Download_Percantage" which contains the value of the downloadprogress in percantage.

Now i want that a function in "MainWindow.xaml.cs" run always when the value of Download_Percentage get changed, so the function can set the value of a progressbar to the new "Download_Percentage".

How can i do this?

Summary:
class Download
-> public static double Download_Percantage;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
-> function which runs when Download_Percantage get changed

Comment: Something like [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Don't make instance fields static, you probably want to reuse the `Download` class multiple times. So when you want to download a file, you should keep the instance of a Download class in a field instead of calling static variables/methods. You might take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8) because that will answer your next question.

Comment: @J.vanLangen it does not have to be static if I want to use it in another class?

Comment: @GameSoldier No. I think you've misunderstood the purpose of the `static` keyword. Try reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members . Meanwhile, for a property to be accessible from another class, it must be marked as `public`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers